IRS CP081 notice - how to claim credit
I have been cleaning up my 2021 taxes and getting my form 940s straightened out.
I received a letter saying that I have credits from Q3 2021 and Q2 2021. I already filed form 941s for all period in 2021 and I am not sure how they get to a credit in these periods.
What is the process for claiming this credit? The letter makes it sound like I need to re-file my form 941, but where do I put in that I am owed a credit or the amount of the credit? Nothing on the IRS website is helpful on this.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance. Forms 940/941 is a purely business thing, and you should consult a licensed CPA/EA/Attorney on the matter. See here

@littleadv do you do anything except vote to close stuff?

No, I only get rep from voting to close. /s Sarcasm aside, out of 4 questions you've asked so far I've answered 2.

Well in all seriousness, it is personal finance when you're a small biz owner and it all flows back to you personally.

As it says in the "on topic" help page, "Questions about small business that have no bearing on personal finance" are off topic. Even if a 1-person business, it's still a business. Form 940/941 is a business form, not a personal form, and it doesn't matter if you are a self-proprietor or a multi-national corporation.

The general guidance from the IRS seems to be to refile the return in question. See here:

What you need to do
If you're required to file this tax return, file immediately. We'll apply the credit amount shown on this notice to the tax you owe and refund any overpayment to you, if you don't owe other taxes or obligations.
If you've already filed this return and it has been over 8 weeks, send us a newly signed copy of your tax return. Be sure to attach copies of all schedules and other documents you included with your previously filed original tax return.
If you want the credit transferred to another tax form, tax period or tax identification number, call us at 800-829-0115.
If you don't file your tax return or contact us, you'll lose this credit. The Internal Revenue Code sets strict time limits for refunding or transferring credits.

You're asking: The letter makes it sound like I need to re-file my form 941, but where do I put in that I am owed a credit or the amount of the credit?
The credit is the amounts you paid throughout a year. Once your return is processed these credits are applied to the tax owed, so you may not in fact be due any refund - the IRS just doesn't know. You paid them something and they don't know what it was for.
Since it's a payroll return, you can't just ignore this and hope it would go away. You need to make sure your return is in fact processed. Payroll violations may be considered criminal, and have very high civil penalties as well.
